# ECDSA Algorithm

Tags: elliptic-curves, dsa

Let the curve
$$y^2 = x^3 + 3x+ 5$$
be defined on $Z_{19}$ .

1. If my private key is $d=4$ what is my public key for $P=(9,1)$ .
2. If $H(M)=4$, find your ECDSA signature for message. Randomize the parameter $k$ (For example $k=2$).
3. Verify the signature.

My steps :

1. $Q = d \cdot P \pmod n$

   $Q = 4 \cdot (9,1) \pmod {17}$

   $Q = (8,11) \pmod {17}$

My public key is $Q = (8,11)$.

2. $H(M) = 4$

   I choose $k = 2$.

   $k^{-1} \pmod n = 2^{-1} \pmod {17} => 2^{-1}=10 \pmod {17}$

   $kP = (x_1,x_2) => 2P = (15,9)$

   $r = x_1 \pmod n => r = 15 \pmod {17}=> r = 15$

   $s = k^{-1}(H(M)  + d \cdot r) \pmod n => 2^{-1}(4+4\cdot 15) \pmod {17}=> s=15$

   $\therefore (r,s) = (15,15)$
3. $w = s^{-1} \pmod n => 15^{-1} \pmod {17}=> w = 8$

   $u_1 = H(M) \cdot w \pmod n => u_1 = 4 \cdot 8 \pmod {17}=> u_1 = 15$

   $u_2 = r \cdot w \pmod n => u_2 = 15 \cdot 8 \pmod {17}=> u_2 = 1$

   $\therefore v = u_1 \cdot p+u_2 \cdot q \pmod n => v = 15 \cdot (9,1)+1 \cdot (8,11) \pmod {17}$

   $\therefore v = (15,8)$

   $\therefore x_v = 15 = r$

Comment: Welcome to crypto-SE! Hint1: ECDSA with prime field (as $\mathbb Z_{19}$ is) tends to be used on curves of prime order, and I'm not seeing that. So I'd double check the givens $\mathbb Z_{19}$ and $y^2=x^3+3x+5$. They are not necessarily false, but they do seem unusual. Hint2: You use $P=(9,1)$ for the base point. I suggest to check how you get from this to the $\pmod{17}$ used in the rest of the question. That modulus must be the order of the base point in the Elliptic Curve group (thus a divisor of the whole group's order), and I'm not seeing that.

Comment: Because $Z_{17}$ subgroup of $Z_{19}$

Comment: $\mathbb Z_{17}$ is not a [subgroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroup) of $\mathbb Z_{19}$. Proof: the [order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_(group_theory)) of a subgroup of a finite group always divides the order of that group. $n$ is the order of the subgroup generated by $P$ in the Elliptic Curve group. For very small fields, you can obtain the group order by counting the solutions $(x,y)$ to the curve's equation (with $x$ and $y$ in the field), and adding one for the group's neutral. Again, that's a prime for most standard ECDSA curves on a prime field (as $\mathbb Z_{19}$ is).

Comment: I understand. Do you have an answer for this question? Can you help me?

Comment: Read our [policy](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on homework. Assuming the (unusual) givens $\mathbb Z_{19}$ and $y^2=x^3+3x+5$ are OK, and $P=(9,1)$: your $Q=(8,11)\pmod {17}$ is no match, drops from nowhere, and also uses an unusual $Q=d\cdot P\pmod n$ notation. First step for (1.) is applying [point doubling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_point_multiplication#Point_doubling) to get $4\cdot P$ (you got that part right), by doubling $P$, then doubling it again; show that result for (1.). First step for (2.) is finding the order $n$ of $P$.

Comment: Again, $n=17$ is wrong. Also, $2^{-1}\bmod17\ne10$; if you don't see this, get a refresh on [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic). Elliptic Curve cryptography requires this, and some understanding of [finite fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field), at least the [field of integers modulo a prime $p$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Integers_modulo_n). You are working into such field when you write $\mathbb Z_{19}$.